# Jquery don't recognize siblings after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

I don't know what's going on with my script.

The functionality is: I have 4 blocks with 18% width and float left. If you click one block, the SIBLINGS will fade out and than this block will animate to 100% width.

If you click wherever (document) this block will return to 18% width and the SIBLINGS will fade in again.

First time it works fine, but after I close and try to open another box, this first box don't fade out with the other siblings.

After follow my code:

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FKae/1/

HTML

```
<div class="tipos-box">
<div class="box box-fechada red" rel=".red-data">
    <div class="box-content">
        Uhul abc
    </div>

</div>
<div class="box box-fechada paleale" rel=".paleale-data">
    <div class="box-content">
        Uhul abc
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box box-fechada pielsen" rel=".pielsen-data">
    <div class="box-content">
        Uhul abc
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box box-fechada weiss" rel=".weiss-data">
    <div class="box-content">
        Uhul abc
    </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
width: 18%;
float: left;
margin: 3%;
height: 500px;
border: solid 1px #F00;
cursor: pointer;
}
.red:hover, .red.essa-box {
border: solid 1px #FF0;
}
.paleale:hover, .paleale.essa-box {
border: solid 1px #F0F;
}
.pielsen:hover, .weiss.essa-box {
border: solid 1px #FFF;
}
.weiss:hover, .weiss.essa-box {
border: solid 1px #0FF;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.box-fechada').bind("click", abrebox);

function abrebox(e) {
    $('.box-fechada').unbind("click");

    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).dequeue();



    $(this)
    .addClass("essa-box")
    .removeClass("box-fechada")
    .queue(function(){
        $(this).siblings().fadeOut();
        $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .delay(500)
    .queue(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: "100%"
        });
        $(this).dequeue();
    });




    $(document).bind("click", function(){
        $(".essa-box")
        .animate({
            width: "18%"
        })
        .queue(function(){
            $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
        })
        .addClass("box-fechada")
        .removeClass("essa-box");

        $(document).unbind("click");
        $('.box-fechada').bind("click", abrebox);
    });


}


});
```

Comment: I don't really follow the logic, but I'll bet it's related to binding and unbinding the click handler on `.box-fechada`. Why are you doing that? If it's because you dynamically add and remove the class, why not use delegation with `.on()`?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the elements being bound to the click event.  You need to rebind them after  you fade them back in.

```
 .queue(function(){
        $(this).siblings().fadeIn();
    })
    .addClass("box-fechada")
    .removeClass("essa-box");
    $(this).bind("click", abrebox);
```

Also, what version of jQuery are you using?  If it's later than 1.7, you should be using .on()

```
 $( '.box-fechada' ).on( "click", abrebox);
```

Comment: Thanks for the .on() tip, but it still not working. The events are binded again on line:
$('.box-fechada').bind("click", abreCerveja);
The problem is that the block that you open, if you click any other block, this block don't fadeout.